# how to get a table with columns named after key in mapping table

Tags: sql, join, relational-database

I'd like a "flat" representation of a table and a corresponding mapping table with key-value pairs, where the keys are used as columns in the result. 
E.g. given I have a table with a one to manny relation like this:

```
Table Items(ID, Name)
| ID | Name  |
|----|-------|
|  1 | Item1 |
|  2 | Other |

Table KeyValue(ID, Key, Value, ItemID[FK->Items])
| ID | Key  | Value  | ItemID[FK->Items] |
|----|------|--------|-------------------|
|  1 | key1 | value1 |                 1 |
|  2 | key2 | value2 |                 1 |
|  3 | key3 | value3 |                 1 |
|  4 | key1 | valueX |                 2 |
|  5 | key3 | valueY |                 2 |
|  6 | key4 | valueZ |                 2 |
```

how would I join/process the tables to get a table like this:

```
| ID | Name  | key1   | key2   | key3   | key4   |
|----|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 | Item1 | value1 | value2 | value3 | NULL   |
|  2 | Other | valueX | NULL   | valueY | valueZ |
```

**EDIT:**

The keys would be variable irl.
In the real world I'm trying to implement a garden-database.
There I have a mapping table "dates" with important dates for the plants - e.g.

```
Table Dates(ID, Event, Date, PlantID[FK->Plants])
```

so if I add a Date with an event to a plant, and another plant has a date with the same event-name the event should be one column.

```
| Plant | planted    | harvested | cut        |
| Tree  | 01/01/2018 | 01/09/2019| 02/09/2019 |
| Tree2 | 01/01/2017 | -         | 02/09/2019 |
```

if I'd add a "harvested"-Date to Tree2 it should appear in column "harvested".
If I'd add a "newEvent"-Date to Tree2 there should be an additional column "newEvent" with NULL entry for Tree1.
…but I do not know yet, what possible events will be stored.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
select t1.id,name
max(case when t2.key='key1' then value end),
max(case when t2.key='key4' then value end),
max(case when t2.key='key2' then value end),
max(case when t2.key='key3' then value end)
from Items t1 join KeyValue t2 on t1.id=t2.ItemID
group by t1.id,name
```

Comment: Well… I don't know what the keys will be. I just chose arbitrary names for the example. so the column names would/should be variable, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name,
max(case when t2.Kee = "key1" then t2.Value end) as key1,
max(case when t2.Kee = "key2" then t2.Value end) as key2,
max(case when t2.Kee = "key3" then t2.Value end) as key3,
max(case when t2.Kee = "key4" then t2.Value end) as key4
from Items t1
join KeyValue t2 on t1.ID = t2.ItemID
group by t1.ID, t1.Name
```

Comment: I don't know what the keys will be. I just chose arbitrary names for the example. so the column names would/should be variable, too. 
I'll edit question to make it clear

Comment: @kai-dj The original question was answered correctly. The edit you have made asks a totally different question. This query will not work for the modified question. I think you should take the edit out, leave the original question as is and ask a new question that reflects the edited version.

Comment: Not really – you assumed the keys would be fixed. I did not say that there'd be a limited set of keys in the original question, nor was a limit implied…

Comment: @kai-dj The proposed solution will only work for the original question. With the edit after the answer was posted this solution will not work. I do not have a solution for the modified question.

Comment: The question was "I have a problem illustrated by this example".
Sure the example was not perfect and I should have made clear, that the keys aren't limited. But I did not ask "How to solve this example" and did not say that the keys would be limited.
If I ask "How can I calculate the sum of two integers in BASH? E.g. <2+2>." the answer would not be "echo 4".